# how to get read permission before publishing permission for uploading video on Facebook using SLRequest?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, acaccount, slrequest

I am simply trying to integrate Facebook sharing into my app, my app's end product is a video hence uploading and sharing the final compilation with friends is what i have in mind, I am using native social framework with ACAccount Framework, for my app to work there seems to be weird logic from Facebook that i need to ask for read permission before i ask for publish_stream permission and that they cant be immediately after(read somewhere), my question is where and how should i implement this logic in my code, heres my code

```
    ACAccountStore* accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
NSDictionary *options = @{
                          ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"My app ID",
                          ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"user_birthday"],
                          ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceOnlyMe
                          };
ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [accountStore
                                      accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

    if (granted) {

        NSArray *accounts = [accountStore
                             accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];
         ACAccount * facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];



        NSLog(@"access to facebook account ok %@", facebookAccount.username);

        NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[_fURL absoluteString]];
        NSLog(@"%@",[_fURL absoluteString]);
        NSLog(@"video size = %d", [videoData length]);
        NSDictionary *params = @{
                                 @"title": @"Me being silly",
                                 @"description": @"Me testing the video upload to Facebook with the new system."
                                 };

        NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos"];
        SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                          URL:requestURL
                                                   parameters:params];

        [request addMultipartData:videoData
                         withName:@"source"
                             type:@"video/quicktime"
                         filename:[_fURL absoluteString]];
        request.account = facebookAccount;
        [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data, NSHTTPURLResponse *response,NSError * error){
            NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSLog(@"response = %@", responseString);
        }];
```

Yes I am missing publish stream permission but i cant seem to figure out where should i put it, this whole code is under one method which is called when user presses a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple. That is my implementation of it:

```
- (void)requestAccessToFacebookAccountWithCompletionHandler:(QCFacebookCommunicatorCompletionHandler)completionHandler {
    [[self accountStore] requestAccessToAccountsWithType:[self accountType] options:[self facebookAccountAccessRequestOptionsForReadStreamPermission] completion:^(BOOL accessForReadingGranted, NSError *error) {
        if (accessForReadingGranted) {
            [[self accountStore] requestAccessToAccountsWithType:[self accountType] options:[self facebookAccountAccessRequestOptionsForPublishStreamPermission] completion:^(BOOL accessForWrittingGranted, NSError *error) {
                if (accessForWrittingGranted) {
                    completionHandler(YES, nil);
                } else {
                    completionHandler(NO, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }];
        } else {
            completionHandler(NO, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```

I just use a helper methods to return dictionaries with options, other stuff is similar to yours.

Then, you can paste your code that is responsible for video uploading instead of the completionHandler calls, or you can use this implementation, and upload video only if the **success == YES** in completionHandler.

Hope it helps!